# Start application with environment from a terminal session

Tags: macos, terminal, xcode

I use nvm to manage my node versions. Now i have to type `nvm use stable` to let nvm set my path variable like this

```
/Users/michaelmalura/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/michaelmalura/.rvm/bin
```

Now i want to start xcode from the same terminal with `open -a Xcode` but the project build is failing cause of this error message

```
/Users/michaelmalura/Development/Projects/Apps/react/node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh: line 11: node: command not found
```

The node command works fine from terminal but not in xcode. The same error appears when i try something like this

```
$ nvm use stable
$ launchctl setenv PATH $PATH
$ open -a Xcode
```

Xcode does not seem to inherit the shell environment when I open it from the command line with `open`. Is there a way to propagate the shell environment to Xcode?

Comment: Xcode is being opened by open which uses the finder to do this so not launched from the shell you are in -

Comment: Could you add 'nvm use stable' in the packager.sh or another portion of the build process, that way you tie the environment needed to the build process rather then environment you launch the build process from.